# Backend not loading completely

Tags: magento-1.8, backend, save

In **magento backend**, if I click on **save button** loads the page but the saving modal dialog newer stop. you see this on the screenshot. Page is not loading but the saving popup is not stopping.

Also if I open a product sometimes the backend doesen't loads the whole site. It stops loading before all data is displayes.

It looks like that page stops loading before all processes are finished.

Not sure if you understand the problem but maybe some one help.

[image]

Comment: Do you have custom modules in your store?  Would something be slowing it down?  Does your server have a timeout if something is slowing it down?

Comment: I guess some of your actions are throwing 503 error. Check inspect element to find which action.

Comment: There are two possibilities for this error 1) try to disable third party or custom module and 2) check server configuration.